# How to have current [indexPath.row +1]?

Tags: ios, streaming, avfoundation, spotify, audio-player

I'm building a Spotify iOS SDK music client and am stuck at how to get it to play the next track.

The SDK comes with a SPTAudioStreamingPlayer takes in the URI of a track. I have an array of Spotify SPTSavedTracks and would like to be able queue/skip to next track by getting the next URI.

I'm thinking I would have to queue/skip using the next indexPath.row of the current playing tracking...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) SPTSavedTrack* nextTrack;

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
self.selectedTrack = self.SPTrackList[indexPath.row];
```

But I'm stuck at how to get the IndexPath.row of the currently selected track, so I can get the next indexPath, or [indexPath.row +1].  If the user keep skipping, I would also have to keep track of the indexPath, as well.

I'm not finding any information pertaining to SPTSavedTracks in the SDK Docs on this.

Sorry, if the title is weird and the question poorly phrased. New to iOS. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not also save the selectedTrack's row, ex:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.selectedTrack = self.SPTrackList[indexPath.row];
    self.selectedTrackRow = indexPath.row;
}
```

Then you can get `nextTrack` like so:

```
nextTrack = self.SPTrackList[indexPath.row + 1];
```

And once the next track becomes the current track, remember to update `self.selectedTrack` and `self.selectedTrackRow` such that the algorithm still holds.

Comment: Good idea! Would I change the SelectTrackIndexPath with [indexPath.row +1] every time a user skip a track?  I know my questions are stupid simple...sorry:)

Comment: @TuanAnhVu You can update the self.selectedTrackRow by adding 1; but if you want to store the indexPaths and not the rows, you'll have to create a new indexpath

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. btw... model, actress, ios dev featured in forbes and elle.  That's just cray cray.